# Como adiciono um novo valor em um array?

Tags: php

Como eu adiciono novos valores em um array?
Por exemplo, eu tenho:

```
foreach ($Read->getResult() as $PDT):  
$pdt_promo[] = $PDT;
```

E fora do foreach eu dou um var_dump($pdt_promo), com os dados que recebo do banco de dados:

```
    array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=8)
      'pdt_id' => string '16' (length=2)
      'pdt_name' => string 'body-fitness-army-by011-4' (length=25)
      'pdt_title' => string 'Body Fitness Army BY011/4' (length=25)
      'pdt_cover' => string 'images/2017/10/16-body-fitness-army-by011-4-1508204418.jpg' (length=58)
      'pdt_offer_price' => string '20.00' (length=5)
      'pdt_offer_start' => string '2018-04-11 10:00:00' (length=19)
      'pdt_offer_end' => string '2018-08-30 10:00:00' (length=19)
      'pdt_price' => string '39.90' (length=5)
  1 => 
    array (size=8)
      'pdt_id' => string '17' (length=2)
      'pdt_name' => string 'body-fitness-ocean-drive-oxbd1101' (length=33)
      'pdt_title' => string 'Body Fitness Ocean Drive OXBD1101' (length=33)
      'pdt_cover' => string 'plataforma-ecommerce/images/2018/02/17-body-fitness-ocean-drive-oxbd1101-1519218895.jpg' (length=87)
      'pdt_offer_price' => string '29.90' (length=5)
      'pdt_offer_start' => string '2018-02-27 10:00:00' (length=19)
      'pdt_offer_end' => string '2018-04-27 23:00:00' (length=19)
      'pdt_price' => string '290.90' (length=6)
```

Mas eu queria adicionar novos valores que vem de uma variavel abaixo de **pdt_price**

Var_dump desejado:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=8)
      'pdt_id' => string '16' (length=2)
      'pdt_name' => string 'body-fitness-army-by011-4' (length=25)
      'pdt_title' => string 'Body Fitness Army BY011/4' (length=25)
      'pdt_cover' => string 'images/2017/10/16-body-fitness-army-by011-4-1508204418.jpg' (length=58)
      'pdt_offer_price' => string '20.00' (length=5)
      'pdt_offer_start' => string '2018-04-11 10:00:00' (length=19)
      'pdt_offer_end' => string '2018-08-30 10:00:00' (length=19)
      'pdt_price' => string '39.90' (length=5)
      'Outrovalor' => valor da minha variavel
      'Maisum' => outra variavel.. e por assim vai
  1 => 
    array (size=8)
      'pdt_id' => string '17' (length=2)
      'pdt_name' => string 'body-fitness-ocean-drive-oxbd1101' (length=33)
      'pdt_title' => string 'Body Fitness Ocean Drive OXBD1101' (length=33)
      'pdt_cover' => string 'plataforma-ecommerce/images/2018/02/17-body-fitness-ocean-drive-oxbd1101-1519218895.jpg' (length=87)
      'pdt_offer_price' => string '29.90' (length=5)
      'pdt_offer_start' => string '2018-02-27 10:00:00' (length=19)
      'pdt_offer_end' => string '2018-04-27 23:00:00' (length=19)
      'pdt_price' => string '290.90' (length=6)
      'Outrovalor' => valor da minha variavel
      'Maisum' => outra variavel.. e por assim vai
```

Usando array_push o resultado é esse:

```
 array (size=4)
  0 => 
    array (size=8)
      'pdt_id' => string '16' (length=2)
      'pdt_name' => string 'body-fitness-army-by011-4' (length=25)
      'pdt_title' => string 'Body Fitness Army BY011/4' (length=25)
      'pdt_cover' => string 'images/2017/10/16-body-fitness-army-by011-4-1508204418.jpg' (length=58)
      'pdt_offer_price' => string '20.00' (length=5)
      'pdt_offer_start' => string '2018-04-11 10:00:00' (length=19)
      'pdt_offer_end' => string '2018-08-30 10:00:00' (length=19)
      'pdt_price' => string '39.90' (length=5)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'laranja' => int 10
      'morango' => int 11
  2 => 
    array (size=8)
      'pdt_id' => string '17' (length=2)
      'pdt_name' => string 'body-fitness-ocean-drive-oxbd1101' (length=33)
      'pdt_title' => string 'Body Fitness Ocean Drive OXBD1101' (length=33)
      'pdt_cover' => string 'plataforma-ecommerce/images/2018/02/17-body-fitness-ocean-drive-oxbd1101-1519218895.jpg' (length=87)
      'pdt_offer_price' => string '29.90' (length=5)
      'pdt_offer_start' => string '2018-02-27 10:00:00' (length=19)
      'pdt_offer_end' => string '2018-04-27 23:00:00' (length=19)
      'pdt_price' => string '290.90' (length=6)
  3 => 
    array (size=2)
      'laranja' => int 10
      'morango' => int 11
```

Código:

```
$cesta = array("laranja" => 012, "morango" => 013);
        array_push($pdt_promo, $cesta);
```

Comment: Uma das opções seria `array_push`. Ou simplesmente `$data[$key] = $value;`.

Comment: @RBZ Eu tentei já usar array_push e array_merge, mas não tive sucesso.. poderia me dar um exemplo?

Comment: Desculpe, não tinha entendido que era unir os 2 !

Comment: Obrigado @RBZ :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta fazer a união dos dois *arrays*: o que você já possui e o que possui os valores que deseja adicionar:

```
foreach ($Read->getResult() as $PDT) {
  $pdt_promo[] = array_merge($PDT, ['Outrovalor' => '...', 'Maisum' => '...']);
}
```

Assim terá o resultado esperado.

Comment: @WilliamAlvares se a resposta resolveu, clique no ✅ verdinho ao lado dela para marcar como solução, assim ajuda outros visitantes