# Como adicionar informação dentro array php?

Tags: php

Galera, tenho o seguinte array php:

```
$postFields = array(    
        'email' => 'site@hotmail.com',
        'token' => '123456',

        /*INSERIR AQUI*/

);
```

Onde esta escrito "inserir aqui", preciso inserir informacoes adicionais dinamicamente, que seriam essas:

```
'item1' => 'Nome1'
'valor1' => '01',
'item2' => 'Nome2'
'valor2' => '02',
.....
'itemN' => 'NomeN',
'valorN' => '999'
```

.Como faço para adicionar esses valores dentro do array acima?

Comment: Pequise por `array_merge`

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como adiciono um novo valor em um array?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/290815/como-adiciono-um-novo-valor-em-um-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tenta assim:

```
$postFields["item1"]  = "Nome1";
$postFields['valor1'] = "01";
$postFields["item2"]  = "nome2";
$postFields["valor2"] = "02";
$postFields["itemN"]  = "NomeN";
$postFields["valorN"] = "999";
```

O "item1" vai como índice e o "Nome1" como valor.

Ai para adicionar os outros valores tu coloca esse código dentro de um foreach e vai adicionando um a um.